# LeafletJS & Cloudmade: Retina Tile Support

Tags: javascript, retina-display, leaflet, cloudmade

I'm using Leaflet JS and Cloudmade in my mobile HTML5 application. Unfortunately I can't get the retina support to work.

I use this url to access the cloud made api:

```
var url = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/{style}@2x/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?token={token}';
```

My `key`, `style` and `token` are replaced by the correct values.

For my leaflet map layer I use the following simple configuration:

```
L.tileLayer(url, {
        detectRetina: true
      }).addTo(map);
```

Unfortunately the result looks really weird. [image: Wrong positions of tiles]

It seems like something is going wrong with the tiles and the position of them.

If I remove the `detectRetina` flag I get a correct result in the browser
[image: Correct positions]

But as you can see both solutions are not sharp on my retina display (Mac Book Pro).

Has anyone made this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Can I provide some other informations to make the question more precisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var tileURL = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{api-key}/1714' + (L.Browser.retina? '@2x': '') + '/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';          

L.tileLayer(tileURL, {detectRetina: true}).addTo(yourMap);
```

Have you tried with different tile styles and check if that might be the issue?